# array_diff_assoc() is considering 1 === "1"

Tags: php, arrays

I am running this code from php.net example

```
<?php
$array1 = array(0, 1, 2);
$array2 = array("00", "01", "2");
$result = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Output of which I am getting :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
)
```

php.net says : Two values from key => value pairs are considered equal **only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2 .**

whereas in the example it considers 2 === "2".

How is this happening ? Please Explain ?

**Might be the case**

If $ele1 is casting integer into string i.e. 2 to "2", then why it is comparing with === operator. There might be 2 == "2" better option and we don't need to cast it into string. Please correct me, if I am wrong ?

Comment: It doesn't do a type-strict comparison. Just like `array_diff` it compares for stringish-equality only.

Comment: See in [the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php): `Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2.`

Comment: Just for clarification: When array_diff_assoc() compares the elements `2` (integer: 2) and `"2"` (string: 2) the integer is cast to a string and that string is === `"2"`; therefore both elements (the integer and the string)  are considered equal.

Comment: It doesn't consider `2 === "2"`, it considers `"2" === "2"` because non-string elements are being cast to string.... that's what `(string) $elem1` is doing to `2`, casting it to a string `"2"`

Answer (score 0):

> If $ele1 is casting integer into string i.e. 2 to "2", then why it is comparing with === operator. There might be 2 == "2" better option and we don't need to cast it into string. Please correct me, if I am wrong ?

It's just the way it is implemented.
If you want another comparision function use [array_diff_uassoc()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-uassoc.php)